# Incrementing while loop inside nohup causes an infinite loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, nohup

while this works in sh

```
i=1; while [ $(( $CONTAINERS_COUNT )) -ge $(( i )) ]
do
    i=$((i+1))
    date
done
```

with 5 dates output (`export $CONTAINERS_COUNT=5`)

the following enters to an infinity loop

```
nohup sh -c " i=1; while [ $(( $CONTAINERS_COUNT )) -ge $(( i )) ]
do
    i=$((i+1))
    date
done &"
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) All the `$(` are expanded before entering `sh`.

Comment: @KamilCuk can you elaborate?

Comment: Great question, I had this problem once and moved to a python script after giving up

Comment: You don't need `$(( ... ))` around the variables used with `-ge`; `[ "$CONTAINERS_COUNT" -ge "$i" ]` is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put script in `'` quotes.

```
:=>sh -c 'i=1; while [ $(( $CONTAINERS_COUNT )) -ge $(( i )) ]
do
    i=$((i+1))
    date
done &'
:=>Mon Mar 16 11:14:01 GMT 2020
Mon Mar 16 11:14:01 GMT 2020
Mon Mar 16 11:14:01 GMT 2020
Mon Mar 16 11:14:01 GMT 2020
Mon Mar 16 11:14:01 GMT 2020
```

Explanation: Single quote will treat string at it is. While double quote will expand.

```
:=>i=4
:=>sh -c "i=5; echo $i"
4
:=>sh -c 'i=5; echo $i'
5
:=>
```

Answer (score 2):

Expansions inside `"` work.

With `set -x` it looks like this:

```
$ set -x
$ nohup sh -c " i=1; while [ $(( $CONTAINERS_COUNT )) -ge $(( i )) ]
> do
>     i=$((i+1))
>     date
> done &"
+ nohup sh -c ' i=1; while [ 0 -ge 0 ]
do
    i=1
    date
done &'
```

You loop is expanded to `while [ 0 -ge 0 ]` *before* executing `sh`. So all `sh` sees is `[ 0 -ge 0 ]` - an endless loop.

I suggest using single quotes for script content to handle most quoting problems and pass environment using exported variable or by script positional arguments:

```
nohup sh -c '
   CONTAINERS_COUNT=$1
   i=1;
   while (( CONTAINERS_COUNT >= i )); do
      i=$((i+1))
      date
   done
' -- "$CONTAINERS_COUNT" &
```

Side note: it's just `seq "$CONTAINERS_COUNT" | xargs -I{} date`